# echo getUrlContent($url) for the last url only

Tags: php, curl

I have a site urls array (php files links) and need to echo each one through a loop
but it showed the content of the last url of the loop only!
I used getUrlContent($url) function

```
<?php

$work_fldr = "work_fldr";
$ini_list_fl = $work_fldr.'/site_list.txt';

If (isset($ini_list_fl)){
      
    $site_arr = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents($ini_list_fl));

    $default_site = $site_arr[0];
    $cntnt_fl = $default_site.'/ptmw/work_fldr/cntnt_fl.txt';
    $ini_fl =  $default_site.'/ptmw/work_fldr/POST.ini';

    for ($i=1;$i<sizeof($site_arr);$i++){

        $site_ex = explode('|', $site_arr[$i] );

        $site_url = $site_ex[1].'/ptmw/create_post.php?cat='.$site_ex[3].'&usrnm='.$site_ex[2].'&inifl='.$ini_fl.'&cntntfl='.$cntnt_fl;

        echo getUrlContent($site_url);
        echo '===============================<br>';
    }

}

function getUrlContent($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'Cache-Control:max-age=0',
        'Connection:keep-alive',
        'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36',
    ]);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}

?>
```

here is sample files contents :

---

POST.ini

```
[0]
Title = "post title"
Featured_img = "image url"
```

---

site_list.txt

```
http://engnajjar2.000webhostapp.com
mhd2020|http://mhd2020.000webhostapp.com|username|1
engnajjar2|http://engnajjar2.000webhostapp.com|username|1
```

---

how can I echo content of each url please?

Comment: Why do you have `GET /1575051 HTTP/1.1` in your headers array? That looks very suspicious - `CURLOPT_URL` should be providing the `$url` but that might be hindering it. You do not need the `Host` header either. curl will supply that based on CURLOPT_URL.

Comment: I was using file_get_contents($url) but it gives me this error "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" so I've searched and got that function and it worked but not well

Comment: From your `$header` array, remove _both_ `Host` elements (I didn't see the `Host:adfoc.us` before) and remove the `GET /1575051 HTTP/1.1` . You can also remove the Cache-control because you are not using a browser. With a saner `$header` array your code might work. Also delete the `$parts` and `$host` lines. They are unneeded with curl.

Comment: I've done all your notes but the problem is still existed!. I can get content for the last url of the array but I need for each one

Comment: I've edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest updating your code with these changes:

`site_list.txt` contains:

```
http://engnajjar2.000webhostapp.com
mhd2020|http://mhd2020.000webhostapp.com|username|1
engnajjar2|http://engnajjar2.000webhostapp.com|username|1
```

PHP script contains:

```
<?php

$site_arr = explode(PHP_EOL, trim(file_get_contents('site_list.txt')));

$default_site = $site_arr[0];
$cntnt_fl = $default_site.'/ptmw/work_fldr/cntnt_fl.txt';
$ini_fl =  $default_site.'/ptmw/work_fldr/POST.ini';

foreach ($site_arr as $key => $site) {
    if ($key == 0) {
        continue;
    }

    $site_ex = explode('|', $site );

    $site_url = $site_ex[1].'/ptmw/create_post.php?cat='.$site_ex[3].'&usrnm='.$site_ex[2].'&inifl='.$ini_fl.'&cntntfl='.$cntnt_fl;

    echo "URL -> ".$site_url."\n";
    echo getUrlContent($site_url)."\n";
}

function getUrlContent($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'Cache-Control:max-age=0',
        'Connection:keep-alive',
        'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36',
    ]);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

->

```
URL -> http://mhd2020.000webhostapp.com/ptmw/create_post.php?cat=1&usrnm=username&inifl=http://engnajjar2.000webhostapp.com/ptmw/work_fldr/POST.ini&cntntfl=http://engnajjar2.000webhostapp.com/ptmw/work_fldr/cntnt_fl.txt

<span id="post_ID" value="240">240</span><br>
<span id="sample-permalink_240" href="https://mhd2020.000webhostapp.com/?p=240" >https://mhd2020.000webhostapp.com/?p=240</span><br>
<span id="wp-admin-canonical_240" href="" ></span><br>
<span id="result_240">Successful</span><br>

URL -> http://engnajjar2.000webhostapp.com/ptmw/create_post.php?cat=1&usrnm=username&inifl=http://engnajjar2.000webhostapp.com/ptmw/work_fldr/POST.ini&cntntfl=http://engnajjar2.000webhostapp.com/ptmw/work_fldr/cntnt_fl.txt

<span id="post_ID" value="1639">1639</span><br>
<span id="sample-permalink_1639" href="https://engnajjar2.000webhostapp.com/2021/01/30/hello-39/" >https://engnajjar2.000webhostapp.com/2021/01/30/hello-39/</span><br>
<span id="wp-admin-canonical_1639" href="" ></span><br>
<span id="result_1639">Successful</span><br>
```

Comment: my friend your code is working as it self but not in my code so I've edited the post and set the full code

Comment: @engnajjar I have updated my example to show that it works for both URLs with the code I put together for you. Can you please accept my answer as the correct answer

Comment: thanks so much my friend it works well but I need to get site list from a file such as $site_arr = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents($ini_list_fl)); and when I do, the problem is still existed but it works by your method

Comment: @engnajjar Updated the example to use a file. Note the `trim()` in `trim(file_get_contents('site_list.txt'))` is important since your issue might be blank lines.

Comment: thanks my friend you gave me the answer I found that I have to 'cat='.trim($site_ex[3]) because I've noticed that $site_ex[3] for the first url it has a space e.g: cat=1 &....

Comment: @engnajjar  you got it